# Applications of Schrodinger's to dark solitons

Tags: waves, schroedinger-equation, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems, applied-physics

The Schrodinger equation (SE) admits dark solitons as particular solutions. The SE and the The Korteweg-de Vries (KdV) equations can be used to model them.

Questions:

- What are the applications of these equations?
- If I work on solving the KdV equations, to what extend the knowledge I obtain is relevant to get insight about the Schrödinger equation?
- Will I limit the number of domain I can work afterwards (compared to working on the more general Schrödinger equation)?

As far as I know the Schrödinger can be applied to (none exhaustive list):

- Studying molecules/atoms and their properties
- Materials at microscopic scale

While I feel that the KdV equations focused more on certain wave propagation with applications to:

- signals

Comment: what do you mean by the KdV is *derived* from the time dependent Schrodinger equation?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "The KdV equation is derived from the time-dependent Schroedinger equation". In fact the KdV equation is known since the 1800s to describe waves in shallow water, while Schroedinger published his equation 1925, hence way later.

With this I do not want to say that KdV has nothing to say about quantum mechanics.

The KdV equation is of particular interest because it is an integrable partial differential equation (PDE), solvable by the Inverse Scattering Method (ISM). Integrable means that one can find in general a so-called *Lax connection* and write the equation as the zero-curvature condition of this connection.

This amounts to finding two $2 \times 2$ matrices $L$ and $M$ in terms of which KdV can be written as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial x} = [M, L]\,.
\end{equation}

This can also be seen as the compatibility condition of the so-called *auxiliary system* (here $\Psi$ is a two dimensional column vector)
\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - L\right)\Psi = 0\,, && \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - M\right)\Psi = 0\,.
\end{align}
The first equation of the auxiliar system can be transformed into the *time-independent Schroedinger equation* by taking another derivative with respect to $x$ and taking the first component of the column vector. This particular Schroedinger equation is what was considered by Gardner, Greene, Kruskal and Miura to develop the ISM, which basically involves determining the potential of the Schroedinger equation in terms of the *scattering data* (which basically are data like reflection coefficients and information about the bound states). The potential can be determined via the *Gelfand-Levitan-Marchenko equation*.

Going quantum now, KdV has still to say something. The integrable structure of some Conformal Field Theories (CFT) can be basically seen as a quantization of the classical integrable structure of KdV. You can read about this in the famous paper by V. Bazhanov, S. Lukyanov, A. Zamolodchikov *Integrable Structure of Conformal Field Theory, Quantum KdV Theory and Thermodynamic Bethe Ansatz*.

If you like these two equations integrability might be the field of research for you!